# C++ OpenCV: Detecting two lines instead of one (Canny & findContours)

Tags: c++, opencv, line, contour, canny-operator

I am currently working on a project based on detecting contours in a picture. I'm analyzing images with lines only, such as [this rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMmFE.png), among other pictures (also colorful). The problem is that using my code I get an [image of "two rectangles"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMFQe.png) as a result, instead of one. I understand the reason behind it: Canny detects edges on both sides of the line, because of the gradient. But, is there any way to remove one of the rectangles (or lines in other pictures) or merge them into one?

Fragment of my code:

```
cvtColor(source, imgGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

GaussianBlur(imgGray, imgGauss, Size(5, 5), 1);

Canny(imgGauss, imgCanny, 100, 200);

findContours(imgCanny, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

Mat imgDraw = Mat::zeros(imgCanny.size(), CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
{

    Scalar color(255, 255, 255);
    drawContours(imgDraw, contours, i, color, 1.5, 8, hierarchy, 0);

    cout << "Hierarchy: " << hierarchy[i] << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++)
    {
        cout << contours[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
```

I've tried to use `CV_RETR_CCOMP` mode in `findContours` as in the example code [for `drawContours` function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#drawcontours) but I get the same result.

I could probably try geometrical figures comparison, but as far as I know, with more complicated shapes (e.g. human face) that wouldn't work.

Another question, why is `findContours` detecting four contours instead of two (for those two rectangles)?

I'm sorry if the question appeared somewhere else, I'll be happy if you send me a link to it.

Comment: I already have, but as I understand it "The Hough Line Transform is a transform used to detect straight lines. ". As I mentioned: the rectangle is an example, I am also working with more complicated shapes (e.g. drawing of a flower, face, cat....) where there are not only straight lines, but also irregular curves...

Comment: findContours has a parameter flag to only find "outer" contours. Use it.

Comment: Use flag `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` for `findContours`

Comment: I've also tried it: the mode `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` is only for the most external contours. If I had e.g. square inside a circle it would find only the external contour of a circle. What I wondered about was if there is a method of obtaining one contour for one line (by removing one of contours or joining two). I suppose, there's none, so thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Any edge detector detects the transition from white to black and also the transition from black to white. That is why in your line it detects two edges (the left side of the line and the right side).

If you test with a filled black square, it will detect only one edge. The same happens with a filled white square in a black background.

For line detection, Hough transform may be better.

For the second question: Find contours detects a white square, that inside has a black square, that inside has another white square, that inside has another black square. It doesn't see the lines, it only sees filled objects one inside the other. In the contour object you can get the colour of the squares and also it tells you if a contour is inside another.  Maybe you can ignore the contours that are inside another.

Comment: Well, I know :) I'm using my program to process many kinds of images (photos, graphics that are also with filled shapes). This is a particular case.

So, there is no known method to cut out one of the detected contours or merge them?

Comment: You can use findContours with mode=CV_RETR_EXTERNAL. This will return only the outer square